# How to generate jar file from srcjar artifact?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I have some `proto` files and I am using `bazel` to build them. I am using [proto-rules-grpc](https://rules-proto-grpc.com/en/latest/lang/java.html#id15) to generate the `BUILD` file for `bazel`. Then I'm running `bazel build` command. But the final artefact is in `.srcjar`.

This also what the [rule](https://rules-proto-grpc.com/en/latest/lang/java.html#java-grpc-compile) says and I quote:

> Generates a Java protobuf and gRPC srcjar file

But I want the final artefact in `.jar` format. Whereas `.srcjar` only contains the `.java` file.

The manual process I can think of is to extract the raw java file from the `.srcjar` artefact and then use them to create the `.jar` file. But this is a bit annoying to do all this manually.

Is there any way to do it without involving the manual process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java_grpc_library`.

`java_grpc_compile` produces a `.srcjar`. `java_grpc_library` produces a `.jar`.

Comment: `bazel` generates two artefacts. One is `X.jar` and the other is `X-hjar.jar`. I can see that they are not the same. Can you please tell what are the difference between them? Didn't find about it in their doc.

Comment: Got my ans. `hjar` is header like `jar` and not the actual artefact.